# Highcharts code with same set of code/data works in PHP but does not work in JSfiddle

Tags: javascript, php, highcharts

I've transferred [my PHP code](http://geodev.grid.unep.ch/mod_test/jsonp_call.html) with the data array the code receives (a JSONP call) to [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/luftikus143/5063bydc/) (with 'local' data array). Strangely, while it works in PHP, it doesn't in fiddle.

Must be something with the data array, I guess, but not sure.

```
$(function () {
var options = {
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        type: 'spline',
        marginBottom: 50
    },
    xAxis: {
        labels:
        {
            formatter: function () {
                return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value, 0, '', ''); // Remove the thousands separator
            }
        },
        tickWidth: 0,
        endOnTick: true,
        showLastLabel: true
    },
    title: 
    {
        text: "Title",
        align: "center",
        y: 20,
        style: 
        {
            fontFamily: "Arial",
            fontSize: "20px",
            fontWeight: "bold",
            color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || "black"
        }
    },
    credits: 
    {
        text: " Source: UNEP (2014): The UNEP Environmental Data Explorer, as compiled from XXXXXX. United Nations Environment<br />Programme. http://geodata.grid.unep.ch. ",
        url: "",
        position:
        {
            align: "left",
            x: 80,
            y: -15
        },
        style:
        {
            fontSize: "9px",
            lineHeight: "9px"
        }
    },                  
    legend:
    {
        layout: "vertical",
        align: "center",
        verticalAlign: "bottom",
        backgroundColor: "#efefef",
        borderWidth: 0,
        floating: false,
        y: -50,
        title:
        {
            text: ":: Legend ::"
        },
        floating: true,
        draggable: true,
        zIndex: 20
    },
    tooltip:
    {
        shared: true,
        crosshairs: true
    },
    plotOptions:
    {
        series:
        {
            marker:
            {
                enabled: false
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{}]
};


/* This would come from my JSON call */
data = '[{"name":"France","data":[[1960,520325],[1961,548976],[1962,585604],[1963,616918],[1964,657130],[1965,688528],[1966,724428],[1967,758391],[1968,790691],[1969,845964],[1970,894468],[1971,942148],[1972,984897],[1973,1050000],[1974,1099250],[1975,1086890],[1976,1134560],[1977,1175100],[1978,1220870],[1979,1262980],[1980,1283650],[1981,1296210],[1982,1327540],[1983,1343900],[1984,1363980],[1985,1385940],[1986,1417210],[1987,1451060],[1988,1518790],[1989,1582390],[1990,1623850],[1991,1640720],[1992,1664970],[1993,1653860],[1994,1691030],[1995,1725650],[1996,1744070],[1997,1782150],[1998,1842360],[1999,1903010],[2000,1973040],[2001,2009260],[2002,2027920],[2003,2046160],[2004,2098230],[2005,2136560],[2006,2189260],[2007,2239300],[2008,2237490],[2009,2167070],[2010,2204450]]}]';


/* load the stuff in the JSON like this= */
options.series  = data;

var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);

});
```

Would be great if anyone could give me a hint what is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing it as a string `data ='...'`. Remove single quotes `''`.

```
data = [{"name":"France","data":[[1960,520325],[1961,548976],[1962,585604],[1963,616918],[1964,657130],[1965,688528],[1966,724428],[1967,758391],[1968,790691],[1969,845964],[1970,894468],[1971,942148],[1972,984897],[1973,1050000],[1974,1099250],[1975,1086890],[1976,1134560],[1977,1175100],[1978,1220870],[1979,1262980],[1980,1283650],[1981,1296210],[1982,1327540],[1983,1343900],[1984,1363980],[1985,1385940],[1986,1417210],[1987,1451060],[1988,1518790],[1989,1582390],[1990,1623850],[1991,1640720],[1992,1664970],[1993,1653860],[1994,1691030],[1995,1725650],[1996,1744070],[1997,1782150],[1998,1842360],[1999,1903010],[2000,1973040],[2001,2009260],[2002,2027920],[2003,2046160],[2004,2098230],[2005,2136560],[2006,2189260],[2007,2239300],[2008,2237490],[2009,2167070],[2010,2204450]]}];
```

[See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anpsmn/5063bydc/1/)